# Leftover characters after comparing two strings

Tags: text-processing, string

I'm currently writing a game in bash that will compare user input against computer input.

I want to find the leftover characters after a comparison between two strings. Below is what I have in mind:

```
user_word='hello' 

computer_word='bxolq' 

compare  ${user_word} ${computer_word} 

compare function: (finds "l" to be equal in the two strings)

calculate leftover word for user (= "heo") 

calculate leftover word for computer (= "bxoq")
```

Now the computer wins because `"bxoq"` length is 4 and user leftover `"heo"` is 3.

I tried `diff` to solve the problem, but the output of

```
diff <(echo ${user_word} | sed 's:\(.\):\1\n:g' | sort) <(echo ${computer_word} | sed 's:\(.\):\1\n:g' | sort)
```

puzzles me.

So my question is: how can I accomplish the leftover comparison?

Comment: puzzles you how? what did you expect, and what did you get? You may find `comm` more useful here e.g. to get an ordered list of common characters `comm -12 <(fold -w1 <<< "$computer_word" | sort) <(fold -w1 <<< "$user_word" | sort)`

Comment: @steeldriver: with the given example I think we want `sort -u`

Comment: I finally managed to get my script working, thanks to steeldriver.
If you are interested you can find it on github:
https://github.com/kzpm/wordwar/blob/master/wordwar

Comment: I notice that `o` is also in common; was it not removed because it's in a different position?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to eliminate all characters that are the same in the two strings, you can do so in two calls to `sed`:

```
#!/bin/sh

player1_word='hello'
player2_word='bxolq'

player1_short=$( printf '%s\n' "$player1_word" | sed "s/[$player2_word]//g" )
player2_short=$( printf '%s\n' "$player2_word" | sed "s/[$player1_word]//g" )

if   [ "${#player1_short}" -gt "${#player2_short}" ]; then
    printf 'Player1 wins with "%s" ("%s") over "%s" ("%s")\n' \
        "$player1_word" "$player1_short" \
        "$player2_word" "$player2_short"
elif [ "${#player2_short}" -gt "${#player1_short}" ]; then
    printf 'Player2 wins with "%s" ("%s") over "%s" ("%s")\n' \
        "$player2_word" "$player2_short" \
        "$player1_word" "$player1_short"
else
    printf 'It is a draw between "%s" ("%s") and "%s" ("%s")\n' \
        "$player1_word" "$player1_short" \
        "$player2_word" "$player2_short"
fi
```

The main operational part of this script is

```
player1_short=$( printf '%s\n' "$player1_word" | sed "s/[$player2_word]//g" )
player2_short=$( printf '%s\n' "$player2_word" | sed "s/[$player1_word]//g" )
```

which sets the two `_short` variables to the value of each `_word` variable with the letters from the other `_word` variable removed.  This is done by using one of the the words in a bracketed expression (`[...]`) and doing a global substitution over the other word that removes each character that matches any character in the `[...]` expression.

Testing:

```
$ sh ./script.sh
Player2 wins with "bxolq" ("bxq") over "hello" ("he")
```